# I can't understand why files are not being written to a mounted partition

Tags: 14.04, server, mount

I can't figure out why files that I'm writing to a device that I've mounted are being written to my main partition.

I have the following devices:

- /dev/sda1
- /dev/sdb1

(there are others but I've excluded them as I don't think that they are relevant)

I mounted `/dev/sdb1` using the command: `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/data1`

I'm using Ubuntu server 14.04 on VMware ESXi 5.5. The partitions are ext4.

To check where the files were going, I had a look at the size of the virtual disk's container file. The container file for the second disk didn't change after I put several GB of files into it, but the first one did. To double check that I wasn't seeing things, I tried filling it up with files. I had a 5GB disc image that I copied onto it and tried making several copies. The 16GB system partition was 40% full and I was only able to copy it once before I got an out of space message. The 64GB partition that I wanted to use should have been able to hold numerous copies.

When I mounted /dev/sdb1, I had to create `/mnt/data1` using `mkdir /mnt/data1` as the command didn't work until I did that.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I checked the size of the virtual disk's container file. The container file for the second disk didn't change after I put several GB of files into it but the first one did. To double check that I wasn't seeing things, I tried filling it up with files. I had a 5GB disc image that I copied onto it and tried making several copies. The 16GB system partition was 40% full and I was only able to copy it once before I got an out of space message. The 64GB partition that I wanted to use should have been able to hold numerous copies.

Comment: Another thing, I read in the documentation that I had to run the `mount` after every reboot. I like to test such things out so after creating 2 folders in `/mnt/data1` I rebooted the Ubuntu virtual machine to check that happened. My 2 folders were still there and I could go into them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After remounting the device, it worked.
I'm not sure why it didn't work earlier and put it down to me making a mistake initially.